Conditionally Show Hide 3 fields not working for others
I am having an odd experience. While using the following code in a SP2016 Script Editor above an EditForm, the functionality works for me in Chrome, but does not work for other users using Chrome and Edge. Permissions are set to Contribute.
This code was gifted to me by Christoffer here
I am looking for suggestions on how to get this working for other users. Thank you!
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    // References to your fields (the columns internal name)
    const MainField  = $("input[id^='MainField']");
    const Field2 = $("input[id^='Field2']");
    const Field3 = $("input[id^='Field3']");
    const Field4 = $("input[id^='Field4']");
    
    // function to check if the column 'MainField' value is equal to 'MainFieldValue'
    function checkMainFieldValue() {
        if(MainField.val().trim() == "MainFieldValue") {
            // True, show the fields
            [Field2, Field3, Field4].forEach(function (field) {
                field.closest("tr").show();
            });
        } 
        else {
            // False, hide the fields
            [Field2, Field3, Field4].forEach(function (field) {
                field.closest("tr").hide();
            });
        }
    };
    
    // as it's the edit form, hide the fields by default
    [Field2, Field3, Field4].forEach(function (field) {
        field.closest("tr").hide();
    });
    
    // trigger the function to validate if the column 'MainField' value is equal to 'MainFieldValue' on load
    checkMainFieldValue();
    
    // check if the value in the column 'MainField' is 'MainFieldValue' on input, 
// trigger the function to validate again and hide/show fields if true/false
    MainField.on('input', checkMainFieldValue);
    
});
</script>


Do you see any errors in the console when other users are opening the form? Is Minimal Download Strategy feature enabled?

Thanks for replying.
I am out of my league on troubleshooting through the Console, but here are two items that appear using Chrome. I'm posting this not expecting you or anyone to troubleshoot or fix. Thx
Canvas2D: Multiple readback operations using getImageData are faster with the willReadFrequently attribute set to true. See: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#concept-canvas-will-read-frequently
and
[Deprecation] Listener added for a 'DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument' mutation event. Support for this event type has been removed, and this event will no longer be fired.

I tried this script on a test site. And it works for me and for users with only contribute permissions. I also get those errors you mention in the console. What kind of list are u using? Do you have modern experience? I created a custom list with the fields described in the script. I only changed this input[id^ to input[title^

Hi again: This is looking like a Chrome (working) vs Edge (not working) issue. To make sure the jQuery version is not an issue, I removed the reference to jQuery in the script. Still works, I believe our company SharePoint comes loaded with some version, although I might not completely understand it.

Is your company using IE mode in Edge? because in that case the script fails on my side.

YES! Good find, Danny! But some users had it fail in Chrome, so I'm not at all sure what's going on. Thanks for all your help & insight.

In IE it fails because of the const. Try using var instead.

Danny!!! It works in Edge! Thank you VERY much. And thank you especially for sticking with it. This not only solves the issue but teaches me an insight for future use. Many Thanks!!

No problem. I'm glad I could help

To provide an anwser for other users which you can accept. I did some testing and it looks like the scripteditor webpart doesn't seem to work properly when using IE mode in Edge. Above script runs fine in Chrome and Edge but not in IE mode in Edge.
